# Give my round image a matching border in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this button in my app to change the language, and the button's icon is a round flag representing whatever language is currently selected. To make the user understand it's a button, I want to give it a little border so I looks more like a button, but I can't find a way to make the border round to match the icon.

So far, the best I can do is add a decoration to the icon with rounded corner, but it doesn't work. Here's the result and the code, any help is appreciated ! (I wonder if there is a solution that would adapt to the form of the image, if I change my mind a decide to use a rectangle image or a flag shaped, emoji type image. Thanks!)

[image: Current look, not quite round]

```
return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: DropdownButton(
        onChanged: (Language? lang) {
          lang == null ? print("Null language error") : _changeLanguage(lang.languageCode);
        },
        underline: SizedBox(),
        icon: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            child: buttonIcon),
        items: ...,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Instead of custom design you can use `CircleAvatar()` and you can give your image in backgroundImage property.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by Chirag Bargoojar in the comments.

What I did was create a CircleAvatar and give it another Circle avatar as a child, the first one creates the outer ring that works as the border.
Result:

[image: result]

Code:

```
icon: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 22,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: buttonIcon,
            radius: 18,
          ),
        ),
```

I'm still going to look for the best possible color, but it does look pretty good this way!

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the radius of your BorderRadius to match the radius of the buttonIcon and give buttonIcon some padding.

Something like this:

```
return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: DropdownButton(
        onChanged: (Language? lang) {
          lang == null ? print("Null language error") : _changeLanguage(lang.languageCode);
        },
        underline: SizedBox(),
        icon: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200), // you can adjust this value to your needs
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10), // this value will be the width of your border
              child: buttonIcon,
            ),
          ),
        items: ...,
      ),
    );
```